# What's different when moving windows around in Windows 10?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, window-manager

On Windows 7 and 8, I used to use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> to move windows around. My standard move was to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd><=</kbd> a Chrome window and then move out a tab and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>=></kbd>.

The problem with Windows 10 is that when I do that the second window becomes unresponsive to keystrokes and mouse interactions. That's very weird. What is happening here, is that a bug? I tried to reproduce that with Firefox but I couldn't. But I also can see that since Windows 10 has virtual desktops and perhaps split screen, it can be a new feature that behaves differently from what I was used to.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut you describe works identically in Windows 10 to how it worked since it was introduced to Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound no, sometimes it shows all open windows side by side, OS X-style

Comment: Do you have a program like StartIsBack or Start10 installed that modifies the behavior of the start menu?